# How to update detached entity using DbContext if ValidationErrors keep rising?

Tags: entity-framework

Got this working:

```
public partial class User
{
public long ID;
public long Active;
[Required]
public string Name;
}

void ObjectContextDeactivateUser(User entity)
{
   /* entity instance has set ID = 3, other props are null */
   /* context is ObjectContext */
   context.Users.Attach(entity);
   entity.Active = 0;
   context.ApplyCurrentValues("Users", entity);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is there a way to update that's row Active column using **DbContext**?
Any way I try, I get ValidationError that Name property is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must turn off global validation to make this work:

```
void ObjectContextDeactivateUser(User entity)
{
   context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
   context.Users.Attach(entity);
   entity.Active = 0;
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Global validation doesn't support validation of partial changes.

Comment: Is there a way to do this globally without adding code to the auto generated DbContext class?